# Do Portable Class Libraries Targeted at .NET for Metro Also Run on WinRT?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I have found a few articles on this topic, but I can't seem to glean whether or not a PCL targeted at Windows 8(Metro) and .NET 4.5 would run in WinRT. My guess would be no, but does anyone else have an idea?

Sources:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HiddenGemsInVisualStudio11BetaNETPortableClassLibraries.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Using a Portable Class Library project, you can build portable assemblies that work without modification in .NET Framework, **Metro style**, Silverlight, Windows Phone, and Xbox 360 apps.

In case it is not clear, "Metro Style" means WinRT.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the clarification. The terminology seems to shift depending on the article.

Comment: It does, it is now called "Windows Store apps".  Most everybody ignores the other name: "Modern UI apps".  Live is rough when everybody wants to sue you.